# How to pass route parameters to webcontroller in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I've read from the Laravel [manual](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing) that I can do this:

```
Route::get('user/{id}', function ($id) {
    return 'User '.$id;
});
```

I've also read that you can pass the route directly to webcontroller:

```
Route::get('user', 'WebController@profile');
```

But what I can't find is how to pass the variable id to the webcontroller.

```
Route::get('user/{id}', 'WebController@profile'); 
// how so that the function profile at WebController receive the id?
```

I feel that this is a very basic thing to do, but I can't find it. I'm new to Laravel, so I don't know the keyword for search this. Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply write up within your controller

```
public function profile($id){
   //Here $id is having the value that you were passing
}
```

Comment: Oh, that easy?? Man, I've been trying for hours using `Route::get('user/{id}', 'WebController@profile($id)');` ... thank you very much! I will accept this as soon as I can do it.